# problem with router and privaterouter / history

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello I have a problem redirecting to a page doing a verification on a privaterouter

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of
>   undefined

on this line:

> this.props.history.push ("/ home");

my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'; 

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login:'',
            password:'',
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const {login, password } = this.state;

        const response = await api.post('/login', { login,password });
        const user = response.data.user.login;
        const {jwt} = response.data;

        localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);
        this.props.history.push("/home");
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

  render() {
    const { errors, login, password, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="login">Login</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value={login}  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
            <label htmlFor="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
        <button className="btnEnt" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter (LoginForm);
```

my router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './pages/login/index';
import DashBoard from './pages/dashboard/index';
import PrivateRoute from './auth';

export default function Routes(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component = {Login}/> 
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component = {DashBoard}/>              
            </Switch>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

my private route or auth router:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const isAuth = () => {
    console.log('a');
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
        console.log('true')
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
            isAuth() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ): (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: '/',
                    state: {message: 'Usuário não autorizado'}
                }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

I basically have my router and I also check if the user is allowed to enter this page, but I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: Can you show result of console.log(this.props) ?

Comment: console.log(this.props) is null console.log(this.props.history) undefinied

Comment: Are you sure? If this.props is null you can't take this.props.history because you will get "Cannot read property 'history' of null" error

Comment: Simm is null, I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: can you place your project to any remote git repository and give me access? I will try to help you

Comment: ok i got put on github now

Comment: I have a problem using git on linux omg

Comment: i try use git status and got this: On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: so, you need add remote origin and push your commits https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/1136998-how-to-add-a-new-remote-to-your-git-repo

Comment: yeah i make this and enter on folder / git status but show on branch master

Comment: And what do you expect see?

Comment: for some reason the files didn't go to my repository

Comment: are you run git status in folder with source code?

Comment: Yes I give git status and show me on branch master / nothing to commit

Comment: You can remove .git folder on root of your project and run git init again

Comment: I already looked for this .git file in all my linux and I can not find

Comment: files with name starts . (dot) are hidden by default, you can run command rm -rf .git from you root folder

Comment: finally got omg

Comment: I also need your backend ))

Comment: https://github.com/lostspirit1/app

Comment: back end is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I read your code and here is my answer

You just need import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and not from `react-router` ;)

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

And use it like

```
export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```